# cflayout: getElementById doesn't work when included in a source file

Tags: coldfusion

If I create a layout in CF9 using cflayout as below:

```
<cfajaximport tags="cfform">
<cflayout type="border" name="example">
    <cflayoutarea position="center" name="_center" source="/example/center.cfm" />
</cflayout>
```

and then create a center.cfm file to be included:

```
<cfform name="myForm" id="myForm" action="post">
    <cfinput name="field1" type="text"><br/>
</cfform>

<script>
    ThisForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
    alert(ThisForm.id);
</script>
```

I get an error:

```
Error processing JavaScript in markup for element cf_layoutarea_center
```

But if I move the contents of center.cfm into the  tag (and remove the source parameter) the code works as expect.  Can anyone tell me how I can get this to work using the center.cfm file?  Or explain why this doesn't work?

Thanks for your time.

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Dan provided the answer already. But just to show it can work ..)

This worked fine for me under CF9. I am not sure why adding the tags did not work for you.

**test.cfm**

```
<cfajaximport tags="cfform" />
<cflayout type="border" name="example">
    <cflayoutarea position="center" name="_center" source="myForm.cfm" />
</cflayout>
```

**myForm.cfm**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myLoadFunction(){
        ThisForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
        alert(ThisForm.id);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<cfform name="myForm" id="myForm" action="post">
    <cfinput name="field1" type="text"><br/>
</cfform>
</body>
</html>
<cfset AjaxOnLoad("myLoadFunction") />
```

Comment: Thank you this did work.  It turned out to be an issue with where I placed the JS.  I detailed what the issue was in the comments above.  I can't believe how much time I wasted on this....stupid, stupid, stupid :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `AjaxOnLoad` ColdFusion method in order to fire off your javascript once the child page finishes loading. You need to define your function like this inside of center.cfm:

```
<script>
myLoadFunction = function(){
    ThisForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
    alert(ThisForm.id);
}
</script>
```

Then, anywhere in center.cfm, add the following ColdFusion:

```
<cfset AjaxOnLoad("myLoadFunction") />
```

That should fire the `myLoadFunction` as soon as center.cfm has finished loading in your `cflayout` tag.

EDIT: The [Adobe LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=ajaxdata_11.html) has a section on how to handle dynamically included javascript.

The relevant section:

> All JavaScript function definitions on pages that you include dynamically, for example by using a bind expression, the ColdFusion.navigate function, or a form submission within a ColdFusion Ajax container tag, must have the following syntax format:
>   functionName = function(arguments) {function body}
>
> Function definitions that use the following format might not work:
>   function functionName (arguments) {function body}

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for the reply but that didn't make any difference as I still get the same error. I had already played around adding AjaxOnLoad without success, but I tried again just in case I had made a typo or something.

Comment: As a test, I added this to the bottom of the page: <a href="javascript:myLoadFunction();">Click here</a> and even that fails with an error (Object Expected).  If I view center.cfm it works as expected...just won't work inside a cflayout.

Comment: Did you use the exact format I had above? Check http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=ajaxdata_11.html for information on that. Edited my answer to show more information on that.

Comment: You may need to add proper <html><head> and <body> tags in center.cfm for it to work. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec10e40-7fdd.html (The function signature should not matter for CF9)

Comment: @Leigh.  Also did that. Both to the index and center files, just index, just center etc. 

I ended up also emailing the problem above to Ray Camden to see if it was something he could shed light on, and he also couldn't get it to work as expected.  Had some success moving the script out to the index file, but that isn't going to work with the app that I'm writing.  After the discussion with Ray I've decided to drop cflayout and use jQuery instead.

Comment: @tHeSmUrF - Weird. It worked fine for me. See the example in my non-answer ;)

Comment: Damn it!!! :) Guys, thank you, your solutions do actually work.  The problem was I added the html, head, body tags but I didn't move the JavaScript into the head tag (of center.cfm).  It's a bit strange as I can put the JS anywhere on the page (and ignore the error) and trigger it with a <a href> tag...works fine.  Seems AjaxOnLoad requires the JS to be in the head tag.

Now I'm stuck.  I've finished stripping all the cflayout stuff out of my app and not sure if I want to bother putting it back in.  Thinking I might just stick with jQuery.  Either way, thanks again for your responses.

Comment: @tHeSmUrF - Re: *"Seems AjaxOnLoad requires the JS to be in the head tag."* Yeah, the link above mentions that. On first read, I thought it sounded overly cautious. But I guess not ;)

Answer (score 1):

It did not seem right to me that the center.cfm file needed to have the html, body and body tags, so I tried this (a combination of Dan & Leigh's solutions):

Main Page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myLoadFunction(){
        ThisForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
        alert(ThisForm.id);
    }
</script>
<cfajaximport tags="cfform">
</head>
<body> 
<cflayout type="border" name="example">
    <cflayoutarea position="center" name="_center" source="center.cfm" />
</cflayout>
</body>
</html>
```

And then center.cfm is simply:

```
<cfform name="myForm" id="myForm" action="post">
    <cfinput name="field1" type="text"><br/>
</cfform>
<cfset AjaxOnLoad("myLoadFunction") />
```

THis works as expected, and we are not sending another html tag, etc in content that is being loaded via AJAX and added to the page.

Comment: *(Edit)* Yep, I was thinking of that approach too. But then tHeSmUrF mentioned that placement is not feasible in his app. Though it seemed a little odd, the documentation does say all pages should have proper tags to ensure they work correctly. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec10e40-7fdd.html

Comment: @Scott.  Thank you for taking the time to reply.  Turned out my issue was related to the position of the JS. I wrote an explaination above.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Call function argument with ID name value.

I call the javascript function with ID value, then use ID value with getElementByID:

```js
<script>
myLoadFunction = function(clickid){
    ThisForm = document.getElementById(clickid);
    alert(ThisForm.id);
}
</script>
```